# Minimize lock held on map — and instead lock on individual item asap

Tags: go, mutex

I want to minimize the lock held on a map of items that can be individually locked as soon as the relevant item has been retrieved.

That lead me to believe that

```
var Mymap struct {
    sync.Mutex
    m map[string]*Somestruct
}

type Somestruct struct {
    sync.Mutex
    Someval string
}
```

could be used like this:

```
Mymap.Lock()
if val, ok := Mymap.m.[needle]; ok {
    Mymap.m.[needle].Lock()
    Mymap.Unlock()
    // do something to this entry
    Mymap.m.[needle].Unlock()
}
Mymap.Unlock()
```

…but as I understand `Unlock()` on an already `Unlock`ed is not a no-op:

```
panic: sync: unlock of unlocked mutex
```

As per https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Golang-Nuts/GeHbpo6AtTc I see that there is no way to check that it is actually `Unlock`ed.

Should I just keep the "Lock" state somewhere or is there a better way of doing it than this:

```
var unlocked bool

Mymap.Lock()
if val, ok := Mymap.m.[needle]; ok {
    Mymap.m.[needle].Lock()
    Mymap.Unlock()
    unlocked := true

    // do something to this entry
    Mymap.m.[needle].Unlock()
}

if !unlocked {
    Mymap.Unlock()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mymap.Lock()
if val, ok := Mymap.m.[needle]; ok {
    Mymap.m.[needle].Lock()
    Mymap.Unlock()
    // do something to this entry
    Mymap.m.[needle].Unlock()
} else {
    Mymap.Unlock()
}
```

Comment: thanks, made me realize that even in the additional case of `range`ing over the map to find the `needle`, I can just wrap it inside a function and use the same kind of well, simple, logic as above